# How do I focus these crystals?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Revealing the unseen - Focus the oculory - Why can't I focus the focus crystal?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35633/revealing-the-unseen-focus-the-oculory-why-cant-i-focus-the-focus-crystal)

In Mzult Aedrome, the wizard who's accompanying me says I have to use some of the spells (Flames & Frostbites) that were lying around to focus these crystals, but its not entirely clear what I have to heat or cool.

[image]

So how do I focus these crystals?

Comment: Related question: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35633/revealing-the-unseen-focus-the-oculory-why-cant-i-focus-the-focus-crystal

Comment: I was going to answer, but then I took an arrow to the duplicate! BAM!

Comment: How can that guy not mention the name of that place ONCE?!?

Comment: Because of the weird name :)