# How can I complete "Revealing the Unseen" on the Xbox 360 version?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have the same problem that this guy had: [Why can't I focus the focus crystal?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35633/revealing-the-unseen-focus-the-oculory-why-cant-i-focus-the-focus-crystal)

The thing is that I play Skyrim on Xbox 360, and the solutions that were mentioned there were all solutions to the PC version.

Is there someone who knows how I can fix this bug on the 360? I don't have access to console commands or mods there.

Comment: I'm having the same problem; only thing is at first I could move the beams of light a bit with flame and ice, but now they dont move at all. Even the buttons to move the discs on the ceiling don't, work or only one works.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Revealing the unseen - Focus the oculory - Why can't I focus the focus crystal?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35633/revealing-the-unseen-focus-the-oculory-why-cant-i-focus-the-focus-crystal) -  While the other question has an *accepted* answer which requires the Console/PC version, every other solution posted (and there are several) does not, and there isn't anything about the XBox 360 that would render any of them unworkable. The nature of the non-PC platforms for this game is that some bugs are not 'fixable' by the player.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz The accepted answer was accepted because it was the best solution for the asker, who is on PC. This was clear, up until you removed the PC tag. It doesn't work for this one, because it's on 360. Of course, you removed that tag as well. In other words, these *were* more different before, until you made them more similar. I would add the tags back, since they are so useful, but don't want to get in an edit war with a mod.

Answer (score 3):

In general, a good thing to try is leaving the area, and waiting 5 in-game days, then going back and trying again. Things tend to reset themselves.

Make sure that you're using the base flame/frost spells, and not something higher-level. Make sure the buttons work to adjust the lenses. Watch the [YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=68FNeOY80VQ) highlighted in the other question to make sure you're targeting the correct crystal.

I play exclusively on the Xbox360, and haven't had any issues with this question in 3 separate play-throughs.